# Jface Label Provider: how to add tooltips to ObservableMapLabelProvider

Tags: label, tooltip, jface, provider, viewer

I need to add tooltips to the elements of a `TreeViewer`, but as label provider I have to use an `ObservableMapLabelProvider` (because of databinding).

This label provider, unlike e.g. `ColumnCellLabelProvider`, has NOT the method `getTooltipText`.

Can someone tell me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can investigate using classes like org.eclipse.jface.window.DefaultToolTip or org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewerToolTipSupport ...